# Ambiguity in usage of the word "Distend"

Tags: word-usage

In [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/distend) "Distend" is defined as :

> (formal or medical) to swell or make sth swell because of pressure
>   from **inside**

And it provides an example for it:

> starving children with huge distended bellies

I wonder if a chind is hungry, how can his/her belly be distended?
Shouldn't the belly's shape be "concave" ?

Comment: What on earth is the reason of the downvote?

Comment: This is off-topic. Did you look up the word in an encyclopedia? Perhaps it could be asked on Biology, it's the closest to a medical SE site I could see.

Comment: @curiousdannii Couldn't it be that the OALD confused the meaning...

Comment: No, that's the right meaning.

Comment: Yes. Biology is more complicated than many imagine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called **Kwashiorkor**.

[Wikipedia decription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwashiorkor):

> Kwashiorkor /kwɑːʃiˈɔrkər/ is a form of severe protein–energy malnutrition characterized by edema, irritability, anorexia, ulcerating dermatoses, and an enlarged liver with fatty infiltrates. Sufficient calorie intake, but with insufficient protein consumption, distinguishes it from marasmus. Kwashiorkor cases occur in areas of famine or poor food supply.

...

> Kwashiorkor is a severe form of malnutrition, caused by a deficiency in dietary protein. The extreme lack of protein causes an osmotic imbalance in the gastro-intestinal system causing swelling of the gut diagnosed as an edema or retention of water.

Comment: Hmmm, Interesting but still the OALD could have used a little more sensible example for such word. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator I wouldn't be surprised if the OED's choice of example represents the most common context of the word "distend" nowadays.